# Redirect google AdWords Campaigns

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-ads-api

I got a job in my work to build a furniture website.
The furniture company already has a website and this website has AdWords Campaigns on pages in the web.
Now i need to make sure when i make a new website(in wordpress).
What do i need to do to not lose all the campaigns progress in the new web?

Comment: I suspect there are dozens of existing questions on this at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. This one is a likely candidate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43387/site-restyling-effecting-google-ranking

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Webmasters.SE.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you use the same google analytics code (from old website) in new website
- Use the js code snippet (if any) of google adwords (or could be "tag manager")
- Try to keep the URLs same as much as possible. In case the campaign landing page URL changes, that will need to be updated in adwords campaign.

Rest things are configured either in google adwords account or google analytics account. So if at all any changes are required (in any of the accounts), those will need to be taken care by the person managing analytics and adwords accounts.